Equivalent polynomials over a finite field
Disclamer. I'm not good at math, and the last time I did it in school was 10 years ago, so I'm writing everything in my own words.
Suppose we are working with polynomials in the space of remainders from division by a prime number $p$ (I think they say polynomial over a finite field). Clearly, any polynomial is a mapping from $(0, 1, ..., p - 1)$ to $(a_0, a_1, ..., a_{p-1})$ where all $a_i$ belong to the field. Obviously, the number of such mappings is finite and equal to $p^p$. This means that all polynomials over a finite field can be partitioned into (?) equivalence classes.
My questions are.

Is this so? And if so, what is the name of such a partition
Starting at what degree will equivalent polynomials begin to occur? (I am not very happy if it is of the order of $p$)
Are there algorithms for determining such classes? Are there algorithms for determining that two polynomials are equivalent?
What other properties does such an classes have?

These are questions I asked myself after pondering whether working with polynomials over a finite field could be reduced to working with polynomials of lower degrees (something like a basis, the smallest polynomials in a class).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Side note: there are other finite fields besides the integers-modulo-a-prime. Not relevant to this question, but just so you don't let a wrong fact get stuck in your head to make things harder later in your learning.

Another side note: In algebra polynomials are formal linear combinations of monomials rather than functions. And, to spell out a consequence of Greg Martin's answer (+1): You cannot get all the functions unless you go to polynomials up to degree $p$. A simple reason is that otherwise the number of polynomial functions would be less than the total number of functions.

(cont'd) But, as made clear in the linked thread, the number of distinct polynomials modulo $p$ is infinite. We do get equivalence classes modulo $x^p-x$, but those aren't very different from residue classes modulo any other polynomial (other than that systems of residue classes modulo an irreducible polynomial are exactly the finite fields).

When looking at polynomials over $\Bbb F_p = \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, there is a very nice explicit description of this equivalence between polynomials:

Two polynomials $f(x),g(x) \in \Bbb F_p[x]$ take the same values on all elements of $\Bbb F_p$ if and only if $f(x)-g(x)$ is a multiple of $x^p-x$ (when the polynomial coefficients are considered modulo $p$).

(In particular, note the consequence that the polynomials of degree at most $p-1$ form a complete set of representatives for the equivalence classes—very tidy!)
Outline of the proof:

For each $a\in\Bbb F_p$, since $f(a)-g(a)=0$, we can show that the polynomial $f(x)-g(x)$ is divisible by $x-a$.
Since $f(x)-g(x)$ is divisible by $x-a$ for each $a\in\Bbb F_p$, we can show that $f(x)-g(x)$ is divisible by $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-(p-1))$.
We can show that $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-(p-1)) = x^p-x$ (as polynomials with coefficients being considered modulo $p$) using Fermat's little theorem.

In each step I've consciously written “we can show” because there's some nontrivial reasoning—these statements do not necessarily hold when $p$ is not prime.
